# compare description of the same name in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have one table with 3 columns like this table below

| name | stat | genstat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | Pending | *(NULL)* |
| a | Received | *(NULL)* |
| b | Pending | *(NULL)* |
| c | Received | *(NULL)* |
| a | Received | *(NULL)* |
| b | Pending | *(NULL)* |
| c | Received | *(NULL)* |
| a | Pending | *(NULL)* |

What I need to do is to Update the `genstat = 'Done'` if the stat of a name is Received. Then if a name have a `stat = 'Pending'`, the `genstat` will should be Pending.

Example:
In the table above, the name **c** has two `stat` with the same 'Received' so I should update the `genstat` of the name **c** with 'Done', and because the name **a** and **b** have a 'Pending' `stat`, the `genstat` of those two should be 'Pending' too.

So the table will become like this:

| name | stat | genstat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | Pending | Pending |
| a | Received | Pending |
| b | Pending | Pending |
| c | Received | Done |
| a | Received | Pending |
| b | Pending | Pending |
| c | Received | Done |
| a | Pending | Pending |

Any suggestion how to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Pending AND Received for a in stat ,what is criteria for choose pending in  genstat?

Comment: If a name has a stat 'Pending' then the genstat will be 'Pending' as well.

Comment: check my answer ,it should work

Comment: To paraphrase; if a `name` has any rows with `stat='Pending'` then set all of its `genstat` to `'Pending'`, otherwise set all of its `genstat` to `'Done'`?

Comment: yes that is correct. Thank you @MatBailie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are no pending then all must be received and left join will return null

```
update t left join(select distinct name from t where stat = 'pending') t1 on t1.name = t.name
set genstat = case when t1.name is null then 'done' else 'pending' end;
```

or you could count received and compare to all

```
update t join (select name , 
                sum(case when stat = 'received' then 1 else 0 end) rcnt, count(*) allcnt from t group by name) 
                t1 on t1.name = t.name
set genstat = case when rcnt = allcnt then 'Done' else 'Pending' end;
```

In essence these are multi table joins as described in the manual

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cf803dc432f6991070dbecd200bb9c9e

Comment: Your first suggestion should have `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY name` in the sub-query

Comment: @MatBailie good point thanks

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion @P.Salmon it works